# How to reassign Windows shortcuts in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I reassign default keyboard shortcuts (such as <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to open an Explorer window) in C#?

Comment: sorry, but this is hardly programming related

Comment: ask how to do it with C# and you might have a shot at not getting this closed :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a 3rd party app, like WinKey:

http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,5506-order,1-page,1-c,alldownloads/description.html

Oh yeah... uh... in C#

Comment: This looks like a great tool, but do you know of a way to modify shortcuts programmatically?

Comment: Oh... ha ha.  I assumed based on lothar's comment that you added the "in C#" bit later and you were just looking for a way to do it for your personal use.  

If you want do do it programmatically, I think it would probably involve have your app constantly running in the background and monitoring keys pressed?

Comment: @Jer I don't know much about this, but maybe there's a way to do it by modifying registry keys?

Answer (score 1):

You could check out this program:

http://www.autohotkey.com/

It seems to be a program that does what you're describing and is open source.  You could open up their source and take a look.  My money is on them monitor key presses.