# Reassigning Windows default keyboard shortcuts in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm re-asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837302/how-to-reassign-windows-shortcuts-in-c) because it was assumed the OP was talking about redefining the shortcut for Windows. I want to do it for my application. Several other similar questions exist but all the answers seem to miss the point.

I'm trying to assign a keyboard shortcut to 'space' in my C#/WPF application, pairing it to a "pause/continue" button. I'm currently trying to use a RoutedCommand similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574405/c-wpf-implement-keyboard-shortcuts). However, 'space' seems to be a default shortcut in Windows (or possibly C#) which re-clicks the last-clicked button. Which is great if the last button you pushed is the one I've tried to assign the shortcut to! But less great otherwise.

How can I remove the default use of 'space' to reserve it for use with my button?

Comment: Have you tried creating a global `PreviewKeyDown` handler, which then cancels the default event (`e.Cancel = true`) if the space key is pressed?

Comment: Most important quality of a user interface is that it is discoverable and predictable.  Change the button's Text property to :"Pause" or "Continue" as appropriate and it all starts to make sense to everybody without you having to write a manual or write any code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the normal Button will capture the KeyDown event if it has focus your best bet might be to listen to the `PreviewKeyDown` event on the topmost level. In the eventhandler look for the Space key redirect this to Pause/Continue and Cancel the eventargs so it will not propagate to a KeyDown event to the currently focused button.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work exactly perfectly, but it got me 90% of the way there. I was hoping to avoid top-level redirection. I had little success getting it to work using the static RoutingCommand, but if I resolved the ViewModel from the ViewModelLocator I could access the Play/Pause functionality more directly.